# Unable to pass variable value to ajax from php

Tags: php, ajax

My ajax:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
          $(".form").submit(function(){
            var data = {
              "action": "test"
            };
            data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
              data: data,
              success: function(data) {
                //$(".the-return").html("<br />JSON: " + data["json"] );
               // alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
               alert(data);
                // window.location='success.php'

              }
            });
            return false;
          });
        });
```

I declared a variable to store unique_id like this:

```
$unique_id=uniqid();
```

I'm inserting data like this:

```
try
{
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO usrinfo (UUID,Name,Phone,Email,Postcode,DateReg,Reputation,ReviewPlus,ReviewNeg,Sex,Status,IsTuitionCentre) VALUES(:uuid,:name,:phone,:email,:poscode,now(),:reputation,:reviewplus,:reviewneg,:sex,:status,:permission)');
  $stmt2->execute(array(
    ':uuid' => $unique_id,
    ':name'=>$name,
    ':phone'=>$phone,
    ':email'=>$email,
    ':poscode'=>$postcode,
    ':reputation'=>78,
    ':reviewplus'=>65,
    ':reviewneg'=>3,
    ':sex'=>$gender,
    ':status'=>0,
    ':permission'=>$permission
  ));

  # Affected Rows?
  echo $stmt2->rowCount(); // 1
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Now, I want to pass the above unique_id to ajax page but couldn't.

```
echo $unique_id;
```

It just doesn't alert anyting, but:

```
$abc="123";
echo $abc;
```

this shows the alert box with value 123!

Why is it so? WHy I coudn't pass unique_id value like this?

MY ENTIRE PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php
//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
if (is_ajax()) {
  if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
      case "test": test_function(); break;
    }
  }
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test_function(){

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php');
$return = $_POST;

  $return["json"] = json_encode($return);

  //below code to store in database 
  $data = json_decode($return["json"], true);




  /*....salting starts........*/


  /*..........salting ends..............*/

echo $unique_id=uniqid();

$name=$data['name'];
$phone=$data['phone'];
$email=$data['email'];
$postcode=$data['postcode'];

$a=$data['sub'];
$b=$data['rate2'];
$subject_rate = array_intersect_key($b,$a);

  /*...pdo.............................*/
  $username="root";
  $password="";

  try {
  //$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users', $username, $password);
  //$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php');
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO authsessions (email,useruuid,salt,hashpword)   VALUES(:email,:useruuid,:salt,:hash)');
  $stmt->execute(array(
    ':email' => $email,
    ':useruuid'=>$unique_id,
    ':salt'=>$salt,
    ':hash'=>$hash
  ));

  # Affected Rows?
   $stmt->rowCount(); // 1
} catch(PDOException $e) {
   'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//query2
try
{
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO usrinfo (UUID,Name,Phone,Email,Postcode,DateReg,Reputation,ReviewPlus,ReviewNeg,Sex,Status,IsTuitionCentre) VALUES(:uuid,:name,:phone,:email,:poscode,now(),:reputation,:reviewplus,:reviewneg,:sex,:status,:permission)');
  $stmt2->execute(array(
    ':uuid' => $unique_id,
    ':name'=>$name,
    ':phone'=>$phone,
    ':email'=>$email,
    ':poscode'=>$postcode,
    ':reputation'=>78,
    ':reviewplus'=>65,
    ':reviewneg'=>3,
    ':sex'=>$gender,
    ':status'=>0,
    ':permission'=>$permission
  ));

  # Affected Rows?
   $stmt2->rowCount(); // 1
} catch(PDOException $e) {
   'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//query3
try
{
$stmt3 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tutoravailability (uuid,week_morning,week_afternoon,week_evening,weekend_morning,weekend_afternoon,weekend_evening) VALUES(:uuid,:week_morning,:week_afternoon,:week_evening,:weekend_morning,:weekend_afternoon,:weekend_evening)');
  $stmt3->execute(array(
    ':uuid' => $unique_id,
    ':week_morning'=>$week_morning,
    ':week_afternoon'=>$week_afternoon,
    ':week_evening'=>$week_evening,
    ':weekend_morning'=>$weekend_morning,
    ':weekend_afternoon'=>$weekend_afternoon,
    ':weekend_evening'=>$weekend_evening
  ));
  # Affected Rows?
   $stmt3->rowCount(); // 1
} catch(PDOException $e) {
   'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//query4

foreach($subject_rate as $v=>$k) 
  {

      $key=$v;
      $value=$k;

      $post_unique_id=  uniqid();


      try
{
$stmt4 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO posts (PostUUID,subid,date,pricing,post_status,UUID,Name,Phone,Email,Poscode,DateReg,Reputation,ReviewPlus,ReviewNeg,Sex,week_morning,week_afternoon,week_evening,weekend_morning,weekend_afternoon,weekend_evening,Status) VALUES(:PostUUID,:subid,now(),:pricing,:post_status,:UUID,:Name,:Phone,:Email,:Poscode,now(),:Reputation,:ReviewPlus,:ReviewNeg,:Sex,:week_morning,:week_afternoon,:week_evening,:weekend_morning,:weekend_afternoon,:weekend_evening,:Status)');
  $stmt4->execute(array(
    ':PostUUID' => $post_unique_id,
    ':subid'=>$key,
    ':pricing'=>$value,
    ':post_status'=>1,
    ':UUID'=>$unique_id,
    ':Name'=>$name,
    ':Phone'=>$phone,
    ':Email' =>$email,
    ':Poscode'=>$postcode,
    ':Reputation'=>78,
    ':ReviewPlus'=>65,
    ':ReviewNeg'=>3,
    ':Sex'=>$gender,
    ':week_morning'=>$week_morning,
    ':week_afternoon'=>$week_afternoon,
    ':week_evening'=>$week_evening,
    ':weekend_morning'=>$weekend_morning,
    ':weekend_afternoon'=>$weekend_afternoon,
    ':weekend_evening'=>$weekend_evening,
    ':Status'=>0
  ));

  # Affected Rows?
   $stmt4->rowCount(); // 1
} catch(PDOException $e) {
   'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
  }

/*try
{
$sql = "SELECT *FROM authsessions WHERE useruuid =:uid";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':uid', $unique_id);
$statement->execute();

$json = array();

while( $row = $statement->fetch()) {
array_push($json, array("id" => $row['useruuid']));}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}*/

// $unique_id=uniqid();
}
?>
```

Comment: It should work. Are you echoing it in the correct scope?

Comment: correct scope? I tried echoing from in the plac eI declared the variable and also tried echoing at bottom after executing all queries .

Comment: Please post the whole code, it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong when you just show bits and pieces out of context.

Comment: Are you echoing both the unique ID and the row count? How are you separating them? You can only send one value with JSON, so if you want to return multiple things you need to combine them into an array or object and use `json_encode()`

Comment: @Barmar, actuallyI was echoing many other variables, but now just the unique_id but still doesn't work! I posted the entire script, see if you could help. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `json_encode` because the AJAX call says `dataType: "json"`.

```
echo json_encode($unique_id);
```

It worked when you echoed `123` because a decimal number is valid JSON. But `uniqid` returns a hex string, and this isn't valid JSON. You need to encode it with quotes around it.